# Difference between objectAtIndex and [0]

Tags: iphone

What is the difference between using the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSString *dir2 = paths[0]; // this throws incompatible type exception
```

Comment: Learning C before you start using Objective-C is a smart move, btw.

Comment: Thanks! I used to program in C a long long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `paths` is a pointer to instance of `NSArray` that you are sending the `objectAtIndex:` message. The receiver returns an `id`.
2. `paths[0]` is the memory address of the beginning of an array in pure C. `[]` and `NSArray` are not the same thing.

Comment: So, when I use paths[0] what will be the receiver type? Is it some sort of int value which represents the memory address of the beginning of the array.

Comment: paths[0] is just a pointer. it is not an object which means it does not have methods. In pure C you have to know what the array contains in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI for all those out there that find this question now...

With LLVM, Objective-C supports object subscripting.  So,

```
paths[0]
```

is equivalent to

```
[paths objectAtIndexedSubscript:0]
```

which is identical to

```
[paths objectAtIndex:0]
```

provided paths is an NSArray.

For more Objective-C literal syntax, see the docs here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html